# amazon web service requirements for linux and windows mssql

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, deployment

My client is planning to host their applications on cloud. And I have been asked to suggest what all needs to be purchased. With all the names / products I am feeling lost. From my experience, these are the following thats needed for a normal hosting.

1. RDS (MSSQL DB) is there need for backup / failover - (units 01)
2. Windows Instance (hosting .net app. Should we host the DB also) - (units 01)
3. Linux Instance (hosting php app) - (units 01)
4. load balancer - is it required?
5. elastic ip (I guess this is static ip) - (units 01)

Both 2 & 3 are webservice / APIs and a management web app. Traditionally, I deploy 2 instances of windows & 2 instances of linux behind a load balancer to work around any failovers / bottlenecks.

Data transfer - I want to host everything within one region (EU-IRELAND or EU-FRANKFURT). So will there be charges

This is the calculation I arrived at [AWS calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#key=calc-82568B49-BBF2-406B-8E1C-E501059559DC&r=DUB).

PS: Apologies, if the question may seem broad.

Comment: You have not supplied anywhere near sufficient information for us to help you with your capacity planning and as a general rule we don't entertain capacity planning rules because they are too broad.

Comment: I am not looking at capacity planning per se. I am bit lost with what all I need to get a basic setup underway. And maybe then scale from there on.

Comment: You *might* be better off asking each of your questions separately.  They're each worth an answer in their own right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely dependant on your application load and availability requirements. AWS is just like any other virtual server environment.

You need Windows servers to host windows apps and linux servers to host linux apps, thats just different types of instances on EC2, the specification of which will be dependant on your budget and/or performance/scaling requirements.

Amazon also offers Database as a service which is basically a pre-configured database server, MS SQL being one of them. You can choose the specs of the machine or pay for IOPS instead. They also offer a multi-site provisioning option which runs a replica instance in a different zone ready to take over should the primary fail.

See here: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/

Alternatively, you may spin up a couple of windows instances yourself and install/configure SQL server yourself in a cluster configuration. You could even install SQL Server on the same VM that runs your application if you size adequately, (not recommended for DB's with a high transaction count).

Load balancing can be achieved using Amazon's Elastic load balancer but I believe it may be limited in how it works:

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

Alternatively you can spin up instances and do load balancing yourself like you have mentioned.

Zones are essentially the different geographic data centers you can run your services in. Each has a slightly different cost I believe. Data transfer costs money anywhere, it always does.

Finally, Elastic IP's are indeed public IP's that you must assign to instances, just like 1:1 NAT. Anything you want public facing directly must have an elastic IP otherwise when you reboot the instance, the default public IP it comes with will change.

Hope that helps, but you have a lot of sizing / specification to do yourself.